# create an object from returned variables of a foreach powershell

Tags: powershell, object, return-value

I am trying to create a script that receives a list of computers and for-each computer I need to create a process, after running the process, I have many variables that y need to append to a an object

How can I append to the object, the returned info of the pcs?

```
#input variable that the foreach need to process
$Machines = "pc1,pc2,pc3,pc4,pc5,pc6,pc7,pc8,pc9,pc0"


#create empty object
$pcNull
$MachineNull
$usersNull    
$object= New-Object Object
$object | Add-Member NoteProperty propiedad $MachineNull
$object | Add-Member NoteProperty users $usersNull
$object | Add-Member NoteProperty computer $pcNull
$object | Add-Member NoteProperty error $false


foreach ($Machine in $Machines  )
{
 #where i make a process foreach computer and there are variables that are returned 
 {
 }
 ###############################
 #where i am trying to append to the created object the returned variables

 #append to propiedad property
 $object.propiedad = $object.propiedad = $MachineNull 
 $object
 #append to users property
 $object.users = $object.users = $false
 $object
 #append to computers property
 $object.computer = $object.computer = $Machine
 $object
}


$object
```

Comment: Can you actually include the code instead of pasting a picture. You already know how to make an object from the looks of it. Create each object _inside_ the loop.

Comment: Stop linking to external files, paste the code inside the text box, select it and press the code formatting button (`{ }`)

Comment: I have uploaded it to one drive OK i will format the code

Comment: @kimopryvt Much better :) Are you sure you want to append values to the same object? Why not create multiple objects, eg. one for each computer?

Comment: I will use the object that is created to create a html report, when i am creating the html its easier to select the object like $object.computers and format it with the proper color or in the right <tr> o <td>.

Comment: i believe that create an object is the best way to easily format but if  you believe there is a better way i will try it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably better off creating *multiple* objects, one per computer, inside the `foreach` loop.

```
# Loop through machines, assign all output to $Objects variable
$Objects = foreach ($Machine in $Machines)
{
    #where i make a process foreach computer and there are variables that are returned 
    {
    }
    ###############################
    #where i am trying to append to the created object the returned variables

    # Define the properties that the object should have in a hashtable
    $ObjectProperties = @{
        # Assuming you've assigned something to $Propriedad, $Users and $ErrorState above
        Propiedad = $Propriedad
        Users     = $Users
        Computer  = $Machine
        Error     = $ErrorState
    }

    # Now create an object. 
    # When we just drop it in the pipeline like this, it gets assigned to $Objects
    New-Object psobject -Property $ObjectProperties
}
```

Now you can create HTML from your objects with `ConvertTo-Html`:

```
$Objects | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head "<title>Kimo's report</title>"
```

---

If you want to test it, you'll need to change `$Machines` to:

```
"pc1","pc2","pc3","pc4","pc5","pc6","pc7","pc8","pc9","pc0"
```

If you want to save this as a .ps1 script file and be able to pass the computer names as arguments, add a `param()` block at the top:

```
param([string[]]$Machines)
```

Now, if you save the script as "KimosReporter.ps1", you can run it against any computer like this:

```
PS C:\>.\KimosReporter.ps1 -Machines "pc1","pc6","pc9"
```

Comment: Awesome, I was just writing a very similar answer. Simpler than creating an empty array beforehand, I've learned to do `$Objects = ForEach($x in $y){...}` and just output the object within the `ForEach` loop, or if you want other output as well you can do `[array]$Objects = New-Object psobject -property $ObjectProperties` and still skip creating an empty array first.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes, `$Objects = foreach($x in $y){...}` is my own goto pattern, but I've heard a couple of newcomers complain that it doesn't read as easy as adding to an array inline. Only way to fix that I guess :D

Comment: Many thanks it works perfect  :')  I've been trying since Sunday to Do This :')

Comment: If this answer has resolved your problem please mark it as accepted (on the left side of the answer is a checkmark that you can click to do that). Mathias does strong work, and deserves credit for providing a good answer.